# Check for Product Category in cart items with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to make a condition, where a function displays on WooCommerce checkout page only, if any product from category `ilutulestik` is present in the shopping cart.

Currently, however, it does not seem to be able to obtain cart info. I assume that because, if I use `if ( $cat_in_cart )` condition on a code, the function I use it on, does not display, even if I have a product from `ilutulestik` category present in the shopping cart.

I've tried many different methods to obtain cart info, but none have seemed to work. I'll include 2 ways of how I tried below:

**Try 1**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'kontrollime_ilutulestiku_olemasolu');

    function kontrollime_ilutulestiku_olemasolu()
    {

        global $woocommerce;
        $cat_in_cart = false;

            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values )
            {
            $item = $values['data'];
            $item_id = $item->id;

                if ( has_term( 'ilutulestik-2', 'product_cat', $item_id ) )
                {
                    $cat_in_cart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

**Try 2**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'kontrollime_ilutulestiku_olemasolu');

     function kontrollime_ilutulestiku_olemasolu($package)
     {

        global $woocommerce;
        $cat_in_cart = false;

            foreach ($package['contents'] as $product)
            {
                // get product categories
                $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( 
$product['product_id'], 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'names') );
                // if it has category_name unset flat rate
                    if( in_array('ilutulestik-2', $product_cats) )
                    {
                    $cat_in_cart = true;
                    break;
                    }  
            }         
    }
```

I expect this piece of code to check if there is a product in cart that belongs to category `Ilutulestik` (or slug `ilutulestik-2`) and if it does, change `$cat_in_cart` value to `true`, so later I could activate any code with `if ( $cat_in_cart )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way for cart items to be used with product categories is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'action_before_cart');
function action_before_cart() {
    $categories   = array('ilutulestik-2');
    $has_category = false;
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for product categories
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $has_category = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Testing output (display a notice)
    if ( $has_category ) { 
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Product category "%s" is in cart!', reset($categories)), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you need to check also for **parent terms** with product categories, you will use instead:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'action_before_cart');
function action_before_cart() {
    $categories   = array('ilutulestik-2');
    $has_category = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for product categories
        if ( has_product_categories( $cart_item['product_id'], $categories ) ) {
            $has_category = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Testing output (display a notice)
    if ( $has_category ) {
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Product category "%s" is in cart!', reset($categories)), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this code, but unfortunately it did not work (notice was not printed). What am I missing?

Comment: @AloSepp So there is something wrong with your product category… This answer is tested and perfectly works with any product categories.

Comment: Could you please clarify? There are no extra fields to enter when creating a product category. name is 'Ilutulestik' and slug is 'ilutulestik-2'.

Comment: @AloSepp The answer code is something very classic and used in a lot of working answers here on stackOverFlow. There is nothing to clarify and nobody can check or guess for your product category settings.

Comment: Found it! I was so focused into the thing, that I didn't notice, I asked for seeing it Cart, rather than Checkout, which I really needed. I think I can use the same code with minor adjustments to display on Checkout.