# Check a product category for a product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to check the category of a WooCommerce product post right after it's created(or updated) and then run some more code based on the category.

To check post on creation/update I used `save_post` and for category `has_category`. Something goes wrong with `has_category` and it doesn't return anything at all. I tried replacing `$post_id` with `$post` and `$post->ID` as suggested in other issues but that didn't change anything.

```
function doFruitStuff($post_id){ // Function in functions.php
    $fruits = 'fruits';
    if(has_category($fruits, $post_id)){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('has the category');</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('doesnt have the category');</script>";
}}
add_action('save_post', 'doFruitStuff');
```

Am I using `has_category` incorrectly or WooCommerce product categories work differently?

I'm used to debugging in javascript alerts, sorry about that.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **You can't use `has_category()` Wordpress function to check Woocommerce product categories**.

Note: Product category is a custom taxonomy used by Woocommerce.

So instead you will need to use [**`has_term()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) with Woocommerce product categories this way:

```
add_action('save_post', 'do_fruit_stuff');
function do_fruit_stuff( $post_id ){
    $terms = array('fruits');
    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $post_id ) ){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('has the product category');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('doesnt have the product category');</script>";
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Note: The custom taxonomy used for Woocommerce product categories is "`product_cat`".

---

Related threads:

- [Display the default discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375409/display-the-default-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/54375782#54375782)
- [Check for Product Category in cart items with WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297453/check-for-product-category-in-cart-items-with-woocommerce/54297629#54297629)
- [And some others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=has_product_categories)…

Comment: Needless to say but that works perfectly. Thank you so so so much! :)

Comment: As product categories are hierarchical you can also use [this kind of custom conditional function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048257/3730754) that will handle the parent terms.

Comment: I didn't even realize I now gained the right to upvote. Thank you for pointing that out too! :)